# Is it possible to install pyRFC onto a Databricks Spark cluster?

Tags: python-3.x, databricks, saprfc, pyrfc

There is a Py-pi for [pyRFC](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC), but like all other C-python libraries, it has a lot of dependencies, and requires the setting of environment variables, etc.

Is it possible to install a c-python library like pyRFC onto a Databricks cluster? If so, how would you have to go about including the SDK dependencies?

Perhaps, someone has tried with the Java version already?

Comment: do the required dependencies exist for Linux?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Whatever OS it is, you need to install a SAP package onto your system pertaining to that OS in order to compile the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's usually done by attaching a [cluster init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) to a cluster. The task of the cluster init script is to setup all necessary dependencies, compile libraries/install packages, etc. on all cluster nodes.  Usually, people are downloading their packages, etc. and put them on [DBFS](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/index.html), and then accessing them from inside the init script using the `/dbfs` mount.

Script could look like this (just example):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Unpack SAP SDK into some location
tar zxvf /dbfs/FileStore/SAP-SDK.tar.gz

# install package
pip install pyrfc
```

Comment: Thank you, worked a charm. 
Also ended up working with the whl package as well and env variables set to the dbfs path.